# JavaScript can return argument?

Tags: javascript

I have two functions:

```
function g(data, i){}
function f(data, i){}
```

I want to call them like:

```
var myVar = f(g(data, i));
```

So `g()` should return `(data, i)`.

Of course, it doesn't work. Is there some way to do this?

Comment: What's wrong with `f(g(data, i), i)`?

Comment: also, this example is extremely academic, what do your functions *really* do? why do you need this function pattern (i.e. why do you "want to call them like" what you list?), rather than using a regular argument passing pattern?

Comment: @Phil, in fact this is my final code.I just feel a little uncomfortable about that

Answer (score 5):

Returning multiple values is not supported by Javascript (at least not in the implementations that most browsers have).

Do the following:

```
function g(data, i) { 
    // some code
    return { 
        data: data,
        i: i
    };
}

var o = g(data, i);
f(o.data, o.i);
```

**Note:**
As mentioned by Phil in the Question's comments, if `i` is **not** modified in `g()`, then you can just call `f(g(data, i), i)` without modifying `function g`.

Comment: i know this solution,i just want to make the code look nice. i even try make g function just return arguments,but fails. Tks anyway

Answer (score 2):

there is, if you use `apply` and make your functions return arrays of values.

```
function g(a, b) { return [a, b]; }
function f(c, d) { return [c, d]; }
console.log(f.apply(null, g("thing", "cow")));
```

This is, however, a great sign of a bad programmer if used for this purpose, so you don't want to do this. If you have functions that take two arguments, pass two arguments:

```
function g(a, b) { return [a, b]; }
function f(c, d) { return [c, d]; }
var result = g("thing", "cow");
f(result[0], result[1]);
```

because you already know it takes, and generates, a pair of values, or use the object pattern (rather than an array) that Der Flatulator shows you.

Comment: Personally, I find returning an object *much* cleaner than using `Function.prototype.apply()`.

Comment: of course, which is why I say it's a great sign of a bad programmer. You shouldn't ever need apply, unless you're doing really low-level JS programming.

Comment: I agree in principal with @DerFlatulator and craft most of my methods to take and return objects when feasible... however I wouldn't say that apply is the sign of a bad programmer... It has its uses that are very valid... its also unfortunately abused.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly like you have it, however you can trick it since arguments is "array-like" ... behold :D

```
var g = function(a,b) {return [a,b]};
var f = function(a, b) {console.log("f evaluating", a, b)};
f.apply(null,g(1,2));
```

gives you:

```
bar 1 2
```

Alternatively you could do something hacky in your (f) function to split the values of the first argument if there is only one argument passed in, but I like the apply better, especially cuz this is horrible if for example your a argument is an array by itself.

Answer (score 0):

Works for any number of argument length

```
function g(){
  return [].slice.call(arguments);
}

function f(data, i){
}

f.apply(undefined, g(data, i));
```